# Show that this integral is finite

Tags: integration

Let $C$ be some constant and $t\in [0,T]$.

Is the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-z^2}e^{C\lvert \sqrt{4t}z\rvert}\, dz
$$
finite?

---

I think I can write this as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-z^2+C\sqrt{4t}\lvert z\rvert}\, dz
$$

Comment: Consider splitting the integral at $z=0$ and completing the square in the exponents

Comment: Doing this, I get $$\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-z^2+C\sqrt{4t}\lvert z\rvert}\, dz = e^{C^2 t}\int_{-\infty}^{Ct}e^{-y^2}\, dy+e^{-C^2t}\int_{Ct}^\infty e^{-y^2}\, dy$$. Does this help?

Comment: I think I have to use that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}\, dy=\sqrt{\pi}$. Hence, I get $$e^{C^2t}\int_{-\infty}^{Ct}e^{-y^2}\, dy+e^{-C^2t}\int_{Ct}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}\, dy\leq \sqrt{\pi}(e^{C^2t}+e^{-C^2t})<\infty\textrm{ for all }t\in [0,T]. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor $C\sqrt{4t}$ is immaterial. You can normalize it to $2$ by rescaling $z$.

Then

$$\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-z^2+2z+1}dz=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(z+1)^2}dz<\int_{[-2,0]} e^{-(z+1)^2}dz+\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-2,0]}\frac{dz}{z^2}$$
and both integrals are finite (the second has an easy closed-form).

Comment: Could you please explain how you get your first integral from my integral? I don’t see it.

Comment: @user710655: by rescaling $z$.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean with that?

Comment: @user710655: how would you make $C\sqrt{4t}$ disappear ?

Comment: Change from $z$ to $\frac{1}{C\sqrt{4t}}z$

Comment: @user710655: that's it. This parameter is inessential.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand ranges from $0$ to $1$, so if the integral diverged it would be due to the tails. But for large enough $|z|$, $-z^2+C\sqrt{4t}|z|\le -z^2/2$. Since $\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(-z^2/2)dz=\sqrt{2\pi}$, $\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(-z^2+C\sqrt{4t}|z|)dz$ is finite.